# Show that the absolute value of z = 1 iff...

Tags: complex-numbers

*Show that:*

**|z|=1 if and only if 1/z=z bar (z bar is the complex conjugate)**

*I have:*

**|1/z|*|z|=|(1/z)*z|=|1|=1**

Comment: Hint: $|z|^2=z \bar z\,$.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I can give you credit if you write a response

Comment: Thanks, but that was just a hint. Instead, I'd be happy to give *you* a +1 if you wrote a full answer (yes, it's perfectly acceptable around here to post an answer to one's own question).

Comment: It was really easy after your hint and I'm so exhausted haha, thanks again.